# Save .msg attachment as a file in java

Tags: java, file, serialization, outlook, attachment

I'm using msgparser 1.1.15 API.

While parsing a .msg I get a .msg as an attachment. I want to save this .msg attachment as a file but the MsgAttachment object doesn't have a method to give back data as byte[].

So, i'm trying to convert object to byte array output stream and then trying to write to a file. Even then, MsgAttachment gives back Message object which doesn't implement Serializable interface which is resulting in NotSerializableException.

I get the .msg attachment like below (Pseudo code):

```
if(attachment instanceof MsgAttachment){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

    MsgAttachment msgAttachment = (MsgAttachment) attachment;
    Message message = msgAttachment.getMessage();

    oos.writeObject(message);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

I get `NotSerializableException` at this line `oos.writeObject(message);` because com.auxilii.msgparser.Message doesn't implement Serializable interface and it can't be changed because its a library class.

I researched and found this option to try and resolve. "Create a wrapper class extending Message and implementing Serializable, then implement writeObject(...) and readObject(...) on my own.".

Question is, what do I implement in writeObject and readObject methods? Should I serialize every property in the object Message or there is simpler way?

Also, is there a better way to resolve the main issue?

Thanks for reading and much appreciate your help.